# Deploy helm chart application to Azure Marketplace

Tags: .net, azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there a way deploy a dotnet helm application to Marketplace?

There are different offers in Microsoft Partner Center like Saas, Azure Container, Azure Application but which should I choose?

Comment: Same question here, more than a year later. Linking to a similar question on a Microsoft forum for reference: https://www.microsoftpartnercommunity.com/t5/Microsoft-AppSource-and-Azure/The-best-way-to-offer-containerized-microservice-solution-using/td-p/51799